# Are there methods to convert between any string and a valid variable name in c#

Tags: c#, string

I need such methods to save some information (for example, formulas) in a variable name.

Of course, it is easy to convert any string to a valid name. But I have 2 unique requirements:

1.The conversion can happen in both directions and after 2 times conversion, we should get the same original string.

Say, convert2OriginalString(Convert2Variable(originalstring)) should always equal to originalstring.

2. The generated variable name should be readable, not just ugly numbers.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: could you put them in a `Dictionary`?

Comment: A little more context on why you are trying to achieve this would be nice.  Could be there's even a better solution.  See also: [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Are you essentially trying to escape special characters from formulae to create C# property names?

Comment: The reason why I don't use a mapping table or dictionary to convert between a string and a variable name  is that the variable name will be saved to an external file along with a lot of other information, and the external file could be used by another application instance. 

I don't want to make the architecture too complex. So it will be much better to save formula into the variable name instead of using other data to describe.
Also, to list all special characters could be tough.
So, I am wondering there must be some solution already although I didn't find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just about the only "special" character that is allowed for variable names is the underscore "_"

You could create a custom `Dictionary` with all of the characters you want to escape, and then iterate through it replacing "special" characters in your string with escaped characters:

```
    private static string ConvertToSafeName(string input)
    {
        var output = input;

        foreach (var lookup in GetLookups())
        {
            output = output.Replace(lookup.Key, lookup.Value);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static string RevertToSpecialName(string input)
    {
        var output = input;

        foreach (var lookup in GetLookups())
        {
            output = output.Replace(lookup.Value, lookup.Key);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetLookups()
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> lookups = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        lookups.Add("=", "_eq_");
        lookups.Add(">", "_gt_");
        lookups.Add("-", "_mn_");
        lookups.Add(" ", "__"); // double underscore for space

        return lookups;
    }
```

It's not 100% foolproof, but "x=y-z" translates to "x_eq_y_mn_z" and converts back again, and is fairly human readable